# Ioc registering error: The current type is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC code and I try to implement inversion of control via Microsoft  Unity.

I follow the document above:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

Here is my project structure:

> Model
>
> Presentation
>
> Repository
>
> Service
>
> Web

Web can only sees Presentation. Presentation can only sees Service. Here is my Bootstrapper.cs file in Web Layer.

```
   public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
        {
            var container = BuildUnityContainer();

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

            return container; 
        }

        private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            // register all your components with the container here
            // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers


            container.RegisterType<IButcePresenter, ButcePresenter>();
            container.RegisterType<IProjeFaaliyetPresenter, ProjeFaaliyetPresenter>();
            container.RegisterType<ISektorPresenter, SektorPresenter>();
            container.RegisterType<IProjePresenter, ProjePresenter>();
            container.RegisterType<IFaaliyetPresenter, FaaliyetPresenter>();
            container.RegisterType<IKurumCografyaLokasyonPresenter, KurumCografyaLokasyonPresenter>();
            container.RegisterType<IVeriSaglayici, VeriSaglayici>();


            return container;

        }
    }
```

I call the Bootstrapper class inside Global.asax.cs as such:

```
  public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            Bootstrapper.Initialise();



        }

    }
```

Here is my main controller:

```
   public class ErpController : Controller
    {
        //

        private readonly IButcePresenter _butcePresenter;

        private readonly IProjeFaaliyetPresenter _iProjeFaaliyetPresenter;

        private readonly ISektorPresenter _sektorPresenter;

        private readonly IProjePresenter _projePresenter;

        private readonly IFaaliyetPresenter _faaliyetPresenter;

        private readonly IKurumCografyaLokasyonPresenter _kurumCografyaPresenter;

        private readonly IVeriSaglayici _veriSaglayici;

        private readonly CevirmeIslemleri _cevirmeIslem;

        public ErpController(IButcePresenter butcePresenter, IProjeFaaliyetPresenter projeFaaliyetPresenter, 
            ISektorPresenter sektorPresenter, IProjePresenter projePresenter, IFaaliyetPresenter faaliyetPresenter, IKurumCografyaLokasyonPresenter kurumCografyaPresenter, IVeriSaglayici veriSaglayici)
        {

            this._butcePresenter = butcePresenter;
            this._iProjeFaaliyetPresenter = projeFaaliyetPresenter;
            this._sektorPresenter = sektorPresenter;
            this._projePresenter = projePresenter;
            this._faaliyetPresenter = faaliyetPresenter;
            this._kurumCografyaPresenter = kurumCografyaPresenter;
            this._veriSaglayici = veriSaglayici;

            this._cevirmeIslem = new CevirmeIslemleri();
        }
}
```

Here is my IButcePresenter. It is defined at the Presentation layer.

```
    public class ButcePresenter : IButcePresenter
    {
        private readonly IButceServis _butceServis;

        private readonly IYetkiServis _yetkiServis;

        private readonly IProjeFaaliyetServis _projeFaaliyetServis;

        private readonly Cevirme _cevir = null;

        private readonly KontrolIslemleri _kontrolIk = null;

        public ButcePresenter(IButceServis butceServis, IYetkiServis yetkiServis, IProjeFaaliyetServis projeFaaliyetServis)
        {
            this._butceServis = butceServis;
            this._yetkiServis = yetkiServis;
            this._projeFaaliyetServis = projeFaaliyetServis;
            this._cevir = new Cevirme();
            this._kontrolIk = new KontrolIslemleri();
        }

        public ButcePresenter()
        {
            //TODO: Fools man injection
            this._butceServis = new ButceServis();
            this._yetkiServis = new YetkiServis();
            this._projeFaaliyetServis = new ProjeFaaliyetServis();
            this._cevir = new Cevirme();
            this._kontrolIk = new KontrolIslemleri();
        }
}
```

I can not define IButceServis 's concrete defition in Unity, because, IButceServis and its concrete implementation ButceServis is at the Service layer. Web layer can not see Service layer. I am getting

> The current type, DKMPPIB.Presentation.Soyut.IButcePresenter, is an
>   interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

How can I solve the issue? Could you please any clue? Thanks in advance.

Investigations:
I have investigate these questions and they do not help:

[The current type is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221635/the-current-type-is-an-interface-and-cannot-be-constructed-are-you-missing-a-ty)

It asks me a create controller factory. So I did. It does not work.

[Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549156/exception-is-invalidoperationexception-the-current-type-is-an-interface-and)

It misuse the DI concept, so it does not fit my case.

[The current type, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493960/the-current-type-is-an-interface-and-cannot-be-constructed-are-you-missing-a-t)

He forgets registering the concrete class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. I cannot initialize the classes inside the class library independently. When the web layer sees all layers, say *Model,Presentation,Repository and Service* and when all interfaces has been instantiated in web layer, it works. Main thing that we should understand here is interfaces inside the class libraries cannot be initialized inside class library.